# How do I code my WinForms application play a system sound?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, windows-7

For C++ there is a function, PlaySound, that can be used to, uh, play sounds.  Is there something like this for C#?  I have an application that I want to play a system sound when it starts, to annunciate its initiation.

There has GOT to be a way.  I hope.

I want to put this at the end of my Form_Load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* 
       A bunch of configuration and initialization stuff
    */

    PlayBeepBoop();
}

private void PlayBeepBoop()
{
    PlaySystemSound("Beep");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [`SystemSounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.beep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that sounds like what you might want:

```
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

It corresponds to whatever "wav" file you have set as the "Default Beep" in Windows' sound settings.

Answer (score 5):

There's three ways I know to play system sounds.

The most generic one is the language agnostic `\a` character to print, that makes a pretty standard beep sound.

```
Console.WriteLine("\a");
```

The second method gives you direct access to a handful of sounds, like 'exclamation' and 'Hand'. They are located in the [`SystemSounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (from the `Systems.Media` namespace) and the usage is pretty straightforward.

```
SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
```

Finally, the last method gives you access all the other Windows system sounds. All you have to do is create a [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), also located in the `Systems.Media` namespace, and load a sound manually with it. All system sounds are located at the same place, so it is pretty easy to do.

```
new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav").Play();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this class to play any sound in ".wav" format. For example you can find windows sounds in "C:\Windows\Media" (Windows 7) .

```
public class Wav
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool PlaySound(String lpszName, IntPtr hModule, Int32 dwFlags);

    public static bool Play(string wavFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            return PlaySound(wavFileName, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the C++ version, but I hadn't been aware it could be shoe-horned into a C# app, so this is also useful.